# Promise not waiting for firebase query to complete and gets resolved too soon

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have created a promise, which would take an array of firebase keys as input, loop them to query firebase realtime database. My issue is even after I use async await, for firebase to provide results back, promise is getting resolved quickly.

```
function firebaseQuery(keys){
  const result = [];
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    keys.forEach((key) => {
      const snap = app.child(key).once('value');
      const snapJSON = await snap.then(snapshot => snapshot.toJSON());
      result.push({ key: key, post: snapJSON });
      console.log(result);
    });
    resolve(result);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`forEach` does not pause for await statements, so it won't work like this (https://codeburst.io/javascript-async-await-with-foreach-b6ba62bbf404). Better to map the keys into an array of promises, and then use Promise.all() to wait until they all resolve. Something like this (just make sure to handle your errors)

```
async function firebaseQuery(keys){
  const result = await Promise.all(keys.map(async key => {
    const snap = app.child(key).once('value');
    const snapJSON = await snap.then(snapshot => snapshot.toJSON());
    const returnValue = { key: key, post: snapJSON };
    console.log(returnValue);
    return returnValue;
  }));
}
```